# playColor = Color.red does not work propely in Java.

Tags: java

What I want to happen is when the mouse is over the green rectangle I want the green rectangle to turn into red, but it does not turn red even though the output says playColor is red. How come? The code is below:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class StartScreen implements MouseMotionListener {
    int mouseX, mouseY;
    Color playColor = Color.GREEN;

    public void drawStartScreen(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(playColor);
        g.fillRect(200, 200, 100, 100);
        System.out.println(playColor);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {        
        mouseY = me.getYOnScreen();
        mouseX = me.getXOnScreen();
        isMouseover();
    }

    private void isMouseover() {

        System.out.println("x: " + mouseX + "y: " + mouseY);
        if (mouseX > 200 && mouseX < 300 && mouseY > 200 && mouseY < 300) {
            System.out.println(playColor);
            playColor = Color.RED;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are only changing a variable value. If you want to paint the window again, you need to force the system to do so by calling `repaint()`.

Comment: it is constantly repainting in my class the extends canvas. it is repainting every 100 milliseconds

Comment: So do you get green, or red, being printed out 10 times per second?

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting the variable to red, but that doesn't change the color of the rectangular to red. In order to achieve *that*, you must call the `setColor` method again on the rectangular:

```
playColor = Color.RED;
drawStartScreen(g);
```

Comment: Where would you get a valid Graphics `g` from at that point in the code?

Comment: @DNA: I don't know, since I do not know the context in which `StartScreen` is used. I can only see its an implementation of `MouseMotionListener`, which has nothing to do with `java.awt.Graphics`.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variable to red, not the rectangle. You need to call `setColor` again on the rectangle.

Comment: but shouldnt it change playColor to red and its setColor(playColor) so why wouldnt this work?

Comment: @user1776707 Are you sure the line with `setColor(playColor)` gets called after you change the value of `playColor`? If so, how do you know?

Comment: Something needs to repaint or redraw the rect after setting the color variable... Just setting a variable does nothing in itself without acting on the Graphic object.